# Xenserver can't add NFS ISO throught XenCenter

Tags: nfs, xen

From another remote IP I can access NFS(debian) without problems typing:

```
mount publicIP:/home/me/NFS_ISO NFS_ISO/
```

When I try to add SR NFS ISO through XenCenter 6.5 with share name:

```
publicIP:/home/me/NFS_ISO
```

It thinks about 5min and then I receive error:
Creating SR

```
The SR failed to complete the operation
Check your settings and try again.
```

XenServer 6.5 is also on public IP

Comment: Have you checked the log files on the server? There isn't enough information in your question to provide a confident answer. That being said, check if you have read/write access to the NFS share.

Comment: I can mount and use NFS without problems from bash on xenserver. Everything works. From XenCenter I receive error always.
I was looking for logs in XenSever and I can't find any usefull informations.

Comment: Check `/var/log/xensource.log`